# asp.net core authentication jwt/identity

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, authorization

i was searching about authentication 
i found out that using jwt for authenticate the the website/app to access  the web api 
but when i want to authenticate users should i use jwt or identity ?

example scenario:
i have a frontend website and webapi for data base communication 
and on the website i have users , admin,owner   (three types of users with three types ) 
for the website to access the web api i will use the jwt but when i want to authorise users which authentication should i use ?

my logic says the website will have access to the data base using webapi with jwt then check the users and claims and handle the users authentication with identity  i am i right ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for Identity User:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

You also want to integrate with Roles:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-3.1

This works really great with Entity Framework Core